# What program(s) can I use to edit a boundary?

Tags: sql-server, editing, export, import

So i've got some shapefiles imported into my Sql Server 2008 Database. A number of these boundaries need to get 'cleaned up'. As such I need to do the following :-

1. Export them from Sql Server 2008. *sigh*
2. Import them as a layer into some editing program
3. Overlay this layer, over a world maps .. like OpenStreet Maps, etc.
4. Edit the polygon(s). Eg. cut one boundary into two .. while following a road that defines the boundary between the two.
5. Export these new cleaned boundaries to files.
6. Import these boundaries back into Sql Server 2008.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Are the programs out there that can do this?

The only thing I found was using `ogr2ogr` to export my boundary (from Sql Server 2008) to `.shp/.shx/..dbf` files.

If we need to purchase a product, then (assuming it's not a HUGE $$$ amount) we can do that do.

If i need to export the data into another type of database, I can setup a another database.

I've spent all day trying to play with MapWindow 6 and QGIS but I'm having no luck at all :(

Can anyone make any suggestions, please?

### Update

> Maybe you can describe exactly what does not work for you if you try
> to achieve your goals in QGIS

Sure :)

Firstly, I can add an overlay of the shape file. TICK.

Next i can't get a world map to overlay. No idea how to do that :( It's like I would love google maps to be underneath my first layer.

Lastly, I have no idea how to cut the shape into two pieces. (and of course, I would be following a road or roads, to define the boundary-split.

This is the type of clean ups I need.

Oh.. I would also love to CREATE a new boundary, by just dropping lat/long points over a map and the closing the poly.

All these things need to be exported to shape files or WKT (that would be better :P) so i can import it back into Sql Server 2008.

Comment: What kind of clean up is needed?

Comment: QGIS can do the tasks you listed. Maybe you can describe exactly what does not work for you if you try to achieve your goals in QGIS. Also, have a look at some digitizing tutorials such as http://linfiniti.com/dla/

Comment: Updated the Opening Topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/).

It seems to do everything I want, now .. especially version 1.8 (as of the time of this answer).

I'm also using the QuickWKT plugin, btw.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are plenty of GIS programs out there that can do it, but I personally use [Manifold GIS](http://www.manifold.net/index.shtml).  You would need at least the Enterprise Edition for doing what you are after, which comes in at $395US

In addressing each of your criteria using Manifold

> 1.
>   Export them from Sql Server 2008. *sigh*

- It has pretty good integration with SQL SERVER 2008, so you can skip your first step of Exporting from SQL Server 2008, as it allows you to link to this data directly and edit it.

> 2.
>   Import them as a layer into some editing program

- No need.  See 1, but if you want to export it to shp or mif or a whole bunch of other formats, you can do.  See supported formats [here](http://www.manifold.net/info/formats.shtml)

> 3.
>   Overlay this layer, over a world maps .. like OpenStreet Maps, etc

- There are a number of options available for viewing tiled image server data like OpenStreetMaps.  These are separate dll files from the main install, so if there is a particular set of tiles you want to access, it can be developed.
- Currently Manifold have released ones for OpenStreetMap, Bing, Yahoo, and Yandex.  You can easily overlay your SQL Server data on any one of these tiled resources, and edit it to your hearts content.

> 4.
>   Edit the polygon(s). Eg. cut one boundary into two .. while following a road that defines the boundary between the two.

- Easy to do.  You can split polygons with lines, draw in new lines, convert existing areas to lines, just about any GIS operation you need to do.

> 5.
>   Export these new cleaned boundaries to files

- Not necessary, but can be exported to a number of formats should you wish to.

> 6.
>   Import these boundaries back into Sql Server 2008

- Again, not necessary, but you can import a number of spatial formats into SQL Server using Manifold.